# How do I implement PWA in React such that my application works offline

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I am looking at implementing my web application as a PWA using React. The main feature that I want to implement is to cache JSON data fetched from API such that it works in offline mode. However, I do not know how to code the service worker in React.

Comment: Well, there's a bunch of articles and videos showing how to make React based PWAs and examples of service workers, just a google search away. I'd start there, then come back if you have any specific questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can start reading the official doc [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/making-a-progressive-web-app) and you should figure out how you must configure your environment (webpack). If you could not understand it, you shoud read this medium article [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/build-a-realtime-pwa-with-react-99e7b0fd3270) or [here](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-build-a-react-progressive-web-application-pwa-b5b897df2f0a).

You need to:

1. Create the file [manifest.json](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/) or [generate it](https://app-manifest.firebaseapp.com/).
2. Bind the manifest.json at the header section:

`<link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json">`

3. Create a file [registerServiceWorker.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47953732/what-does-registerserviceworker-do-in-react-js), you can find help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53737280/how-to-add-service-worker-in-react-project)
4. Write your React App.
5. Choose an offline strategy to store data (for example, you can use [redux offline](https://hackernoon.com/introducing-redux-offline-offline-first-architecture-for-progressive-web-applications-and-react-68c5167ecfe0) or [redux persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)).